# nonnegative complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am reading Axler's LA Done Right and there is this sentence that says a complex number is nonnegative iff it has nonnegative root ( page 225, positive operators)
Taking contrapositive , a number is negative iff it has a negative square root but -1 for example doesnt have negative square root yet i think is considered negative .(supposing i am not mistaken)

Ps: there is a quite ,almost actually same, question asked here but i could not find answer to my question there .

Comment: That is not the contrapositive of that statement.

Comment: Negation of non-negative is  not negative. $1+i$ is neither non-negative nor negative.

Comment: A non-negative complex number *could* mean a real number $\ge 0$. If that's not what it means there, please quote the complete definition literally, including any necessary context.

Comment: "a com-
plex number z is nonnegative if and
only if it has a nonnegative square root"

Comment: then if this is not the negation , nonnegative complex numbers are just Real numbers from 0 to positive infinity (0 included) i guess

Comment: As @KaviRamaMurthy pointed out,  your counterpositive  is incorrect. The negation of "nonnegative square root" is not "negative square root". Complex number and their square roots can be nonnegative, negative or nonreal numbers.  There are three possiblities.

Answer (score 1):

> I am reading Axler's LA Done Right and there is this sentence that says a complex number is nonnegative iff it has nonnegative root
>
> Taking contrapositive , a number is negative iff it has a negative square root

I agree with your contrapositive; however, under this interpretation, the given statement is false (as you have shown).

The author's *intended interpretation* of a "nonnegative complex number", though, is precisely $[0,\infty).$ (As such, the author would consider $3+7i$ as neither negative nor nonnegative.) Under this interpretation, here's the correct contrapositive:

*a complex number has a negative real part or nonzero imaginary part iff its square root has a negative real part or nonzero imaginary part*.

P.S. While I call $7$ a positive (real) number and a nonnegative (real) number, I think it is bad practice to call it a "positive" *complex number* or a "nonnegative" *complex number*.